# Solving a non-linear system of three equations (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

{a*[1+b*(5+c)]}^(-1/2) = 2388;

{a*[1+b*(5+c)]}^(-1/2) = 2633;

{a*[1+b*(5+c)]}^(-1/2) = 2763;

for which I need to get the values of a, b and c. Can anyone advise on how to proceed? I'm not sure which MATLAB function to use, i tried a normal "solve" as

```
syms x y z 

eqn1 = (x*(1+y*(5+z)))^(-1/2) == 2388;
eqn2 = (x*(1+y*(5+z)))^(-1/2) == 2633;
eqn3 = (x*(1+y*(5+z)))^(-1/2) == 2763;

solutions = solve([eqn1 eqn2 eqn2],(x,y,z));
```

but it clearly doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: your equations are impossible? how could a single value for x,y,z produce, in the exact same equation, 3 values? a=1, a=2 is an imposible set of equations, its either one, or the other. Its the same with yours. You need 3 equations to solve your system, but you only have 1 equation, with 3 different results after applying it

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is what @AnderBiguri already mentioned: The same expression cannot simultaniously have multiple values, so there is no hope of actually finding a solution.

The second part is that your syntax is incorrect: Lists/Arrays must be written with square brackets instead of parenthesis, as the error message that you get by running this is probably gonna tell you. I recommend reading the example from [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html).